# Do linux distros for WSL on Windows 10 need to be installed for each user?

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some Linux distros installed for WSL as one user.   For another user to use a Linux distro, does that user need to run the install again or can the two windows accounts share access to the distro app?

Comment: Have you tried launching the application as the second user?  Edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: If you download/install it from Windows Store then YES. If you install it manually then there is some trick. You can find many procedure here (Superuser) to install distribution in WSL manually (without Windows Store).

Comment: I did download from the Windows store.  Thank you.